# How do I fix this "no persistent classes found for query class" message?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jboss, zk

I am creating a web application using zkoss 5.0.4, Spring 3.0.3, Hibernate 3, and JpA 1.0 with JBOSS 5.1 GA (with JDK support).

The project compiles fine with JBOSS. But it seems that persitence is not applying for some reason.

When I run an application in the console, it displays the following:

```
10:07:35,265 WARN  [QuerySplitter] no persistent classes found for query class: from org.zkforge.zktodo2.Reminder
```

Following is list of jar files that I am using in the `/WEB-INF/lib` directory.

```
aopalliance.jar  
asm-1.5.3.jar  
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar  
cglib-2.1_3.jar  
commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar  
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar  
commons-io.jar  
commons-pool-1.3.jar  
ehcache-1.2.3.jar  
fckez.jar  
groovy.jar  
jruby.jar  
js.jar  
junit-3.8.1.jar  
jython.jar  
org.springframework.aop-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.asm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.expression-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.instrument-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar   
org.springframework.jms-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.orm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.oxm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.test-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
org.springframework.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar  
zcommon.jar  
zcommons-el.jar  
zhtml.jar  
zk.jar  
zkplus.jar  
zul.jar  
zweb.jar
```

Following is my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
< web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
 xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">  

  < display-name >  
    zk5
   < / display-name >    


 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:dataSourceContext.xml,classpath:spring-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <listener>
  <!-- The Spring RequestContextLister uses thread bound variables so to 
  use this Spring freatures requires that we apply <disable-event-thread /> 
  within zk.xml -->
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>





  <listener>
   < description>
   Used to cleanup when a session is destroyed< / description>
   < display-name>

   ZK Session cleaner< / display-name>

   <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
   <description>
   The ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
   <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
   org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
    <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
   <description>
   The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
   <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
   org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  < welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.zul</welcome-file>
  < / welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Following is my `spring-context.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
 ">

 <!-- 
    JPA config   
    --> 



 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"  
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"  
  p:persistenceUnitName="ExamplePU"  
  p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml"  
  p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"  
  >  
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">  
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"  
    p:showSql="true"  
    p:generateDdl="true">  
   </bean>  
  </property>  
  <property name="jpaProperties">  
   <value>  
   hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy  
   hibernate.dialect=${hibernate.dialect}  
   hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  
   </value>  
  </property>  
 </bean>  

 <bean id="transactionManager"  
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"   
  p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"  
 />  

 <tx:annotation-driven />  

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />  

    <!-- 
    JPA helpers
    --> 

    <bean id="basicDao" class="org.zkforge.zktodo2.BasicDao" />  

    <!-- 
    First article classes
    --> 

 <bean id="reminderService" class="org.zkforge.zktodo2.ReminderService"   
  p:basicDao-ref="basicDao"
 />  

 <bean id="toDoControllerV1" class="org.zkforge.zktodo2.ZkToDoControllerV1"  
  p:reminderService-ref="reminderService" scope="prototype"  
 />  

    <!-- 
    Data binding enhancement classes
    --> 

 <!-- 
 Note that the following bean is session scoped. 
 --> 
 <bean id="toDoModel" class="org.zkforge.zktodo2.ZkToDoModelImpl" 
   p:reminderService-ref="reminderService" scope="session">
  <!-- 
  // scoped proxy is commented out as only referenced by a prototype bean
  // if you wanted to pass this bean to a singleton you need to include
  // the following configurration.   
  <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
  --> 
 </bean>

 <bean id="toDoControllerV2" class="org.zkforge.zktodo2.ZkToDoControllerV2" 
  p:toDoModel-ref="toDoModel" scope="prototype"
 />

</beans>
```

Following is my `dataSourceContext.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
 ">

 <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
  destroy-method="close"
  p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}"
  p:url="${jdbc.url}"
  p:username="${jdbc.username}"
  p:password="${jdbc.password}" />



 <!-- 
    Injected properties
    --> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="locations">
     <list>
            <value>classpath:zktodo2.properties</value>
     </list>
     </property>

    </bean>


</beans>
```

Following is my zktodo2.properties file

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:salvation
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
jdbc.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Following is my compiling stuff from JBOSS server:

```
10:06:41,000 INFO  [PersistenceUnitDeployment] Starting persistence unit  persistence.unit:unitName=#ExamplePU  
10:06:41,156 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA  
10:06:41,156 INFO  [Environment] Hibernate 3.3.1.GA  
10:06:41,171 INFO  [Environment] hibernate.properties not found  
10:06:41,171 INFO  [Environment] Bytecode provider name : javassist  
10:06:41,171 INFO  [Environment] using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling  
10:06:41,343 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA  
10:06:41,343 INFO  [Version] Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0.GA  
10:06:41,375 INFO  [Ejb3Configuration] Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [  
 name: ExamplePU  
 ...]  
10:06:41,375 WARN  [Ejb3Configuration] Persistence provider caller does not implement the EJB3 spec correctly. PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoader() is null.
10:06:41,515 INFO  [AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from annotated class: org.zkforge.zktodo2.Reminder  
10:06:41,546 INFO  [EntityBinder] Bind entity org.zkforge.zktodo2.Reminder on table REMINDER  
10:06:41,593 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Validator 3.1.0.GA  
10:06:41,625 INFO  [HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister] Unable to find   org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.  
10:06:41,687 INFO  [ConnectionProviderFactory] Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider  
10:06:41,703 INFO  [InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider] Using provided datasource  
10:06:41,734 INFO  [SettingsFactory] RDBMS: HSQL Database Engine, version: 1.8.0  
10:06:41,734 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC driver: HSQL Database Engine Driver, version: 1.8.0  
10:06:41,781 INFO  [Dialect] Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [TransactionFactoryFactory] Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [TransactionManagerLookupFactory] instantiating TransactionManagerLookup: org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [TransactionManagerLookupFactory] instantiated TransactionManagerLookup  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch size: 15  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Scrollable result sets: enabled  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Connection release mode: auto  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default batch fetch size: 1  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Generate SQL with comments: disabled  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled  
10:06:41,796 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query translator:   org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
10:06:41,812 INFO  [ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
10:06:41,812 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query language substitutions: {}  
10:06:41,812 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled  
10:06:41,812 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Second-level cache: enabled  
10:06:41,812 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query cache: disabled  
10:06:41,812 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Cache region factory :   org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge  
10:06:41,828 INFO  [RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge] Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider  
10:06:41,828 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled  
10:06:41,828 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Cache region prefix: persistence.unit:unitName=#ExamplePU  
10:06:41,828 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Structured second-level cache entries: disabled  
10:06:41,828 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Statistics: disabled  
10:06:41,828 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled  
10:06:41,828 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default entity-mode: pojo  
10:06:41,828 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Named query checking : enabled  
10:06:41,875 INFO  [SessionFactoryImpl] building session factory  
10:06:42,046 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Factory name: persistence.unit:unitName=#ExamplePU  
10:06:42,046 INFO  [NamingHelper] JNDI InitialContext properties:{java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces}  
10:06:42,046 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Bound factory to JNDI name: persistence.unit:unitName=#ExamplePU  
10:06:42,046 WARN  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] InitialContext did not implement EventContext  
10:06:42,046 INFO  [NamingHelper] JNDI InitialContext properties:{java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces}  
10:06:42,046 WARN  [SessionFactoryImpl] JTASessionContext being used with JDBCTransactionFactory; auto-flush will not operate correctly with getCurrentSession()  
10:06:42,062 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/zk5  
10:06:42,171 INFO  [[/zk5]] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext  
10:06:42,171 INFO  [ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started  
10:06:42,906 INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Oct 02 10:06:42 IST 2010]; root of context hierarchy  
10:06:42,953 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [dataSourceContext.xml]  
10:06:43,046 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-context.xml]  
10:06:43,171 INFO  [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from class path resource [zktodo2.properties]  
10:06:43,203 INFO  [DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@10fe280: defining beans   [dataSource,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,basicDao,reminderService,toDoControllerV1,toDoModel,toDoControllerV2]; root of factory hierarchy  
10:06:43,296 INFO  [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'ExamplePU'  
10:06:43,296 INFO  [Ejb3Configuration] Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
 name: ExamplePU
 ...]  
10:06:43,296 INFO  [HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister] Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.  
10:06:43,296 INFO  [ConnectionProviderFactory] Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider  
10:06:43,296 INFO  [InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider] Using provided datasource  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] RDBMS: HSQL Database Engine, version: 1.8.0  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC driver: HSQL Database Engine Driver, version: 1.8.0  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [Dialect] Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [TransactionFactoryFactory] Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [TransactionManagerLookupFactory] No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch size: 15  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Scrollable result sets: enabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Connection release mode: auto  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default batch fetch size: 1  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Generate SQL with comments: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query language substitutions: {}  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Second-level cache: enabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Query cache: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Cache region factory : org.hibernate.cache.impl.NoCachingRegionFactory  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Structured second-level cache entries: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Echoing all SQL to stdout  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Statistics: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Default entity-mode: pojo  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SettingsFactory] Named query checking : enabled  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SessionFactoryImpl] building session factory  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SchemaUpdate] Running hbm2ddl schema update  
10:06:43,312 INFO  [SchemaUpdate] fetching database metadata  
10:06:43,328 INFO  [SchemaUpdate] updating schema  
10:06:43,328 INFO  [SchemaUpdate] schema update complete  
10:06:43,484 INFO  [ContextLoader] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1313 ms  
10:06:43,500 INFO  [zkoss] Starting ZK 5.0.4 CE (build: 2010083112)  
10:06:43,515 INFO  [zkoss] Loading system default  
10:06:43,625 INFO  [zkoss] Parsing jndi:/localhost/zk5/WEB-INF/zk.xml  
10:06:43,625 INFO  [zkoss] The event processing thread is disabled  
10:07:35,265 WARN  [QuerySplitter] no persistent classes found for query class: from org.zkforge.zktodo2.Reminder
```

Please let me know if you need anything else from my side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the following in my persistence file and it started fine.

```
< class >org.zkforge.zktodo2.Reminder< / class >
```

Adding the above line created the table in the database, and the persistence error is gone.

I do not know why do we need to add it. Is there any reason? Shouldn't Spring or Hibernate should get that thing from Reminder.java file?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the wrong `sessionFactory` configuration `packagesToScan` that was causing the problem

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    ....
<!-- package was incorrect here -->
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo.test.bean"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The log file has the following:

> ```
> 10:06:41,375 WARN [Ejb3Configuration] Persistence
> ```
>
> provider caller does not implement the
>   EJB3 spec correctly.
>   PersistenceUnitInfo.getNewTempClassLoader()
>   is null. 10:06:41,515 INFO
>   [AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from
>   annotated class:
>   org.zkforge.zktodo2.Reminder

I think you should relook at *Reminder* class.

Comment: Hello Raghuram, I did not get you exactly. But Reminder class seems okay to me.