# Outsourcing POJOs + DAOs + Service in Spring-Hibernate-Maven-Web App causes ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Edit: This is a duplicate of [How do I fix this "no persistent classes found for query class" message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844521)

I have two web-projects which are supposed to share a common database, hence also the corresponding POJOs, DAOs and Services. My plan is to outsource these common classes into a third maven project, which I will install into my local maven repository and specify as dependencies in those other two objects' POM.xml files. In order to demonstrate the issue I will merely focus on one of those including projects (a REST API).

Merging all files into one project will yield this setup:

```
User
|
|- src/main/java
|   |
|   |- de.user.controller
|   |   |
|   |   |- MyController.java
|   |
|   |- de.user.dao
|   |   |
|   |   |- UserDao.java
|   |
|   |- de.user.entity
|   |   |
|   |   |- User.java
|   |
|   |- de.user.dao
|       |
|       |- UserService.java
|
|- src/main/resources/META-INF
|   |
|   |- persistence.xml
|
|- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
    |
    |- applicationContext.xml
    |
    |- rest-servlet.xml
    |
    |- web.xml
```

At this stage everything is working fine, the project can be deployed and when I call the URI to retrieve all Users from the underlying database, the correct JSON-String is printed in my webbrowser.

Now I setup a second maven project and included it as dependency in the User project:

User/pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.user</groupId>
    <artifactId>user</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>User</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.user</groupId>
            <artifactId>usercommon</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

UserCommon/pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.user</groupId>
    <artifactId>usercommon</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>   
</project>
```

At this stage I use my Eclipse's Refactor -> Move tool to move the dao, entity and service package into the UserCommon project, use mvn clean install and build the User project. So far so good, all references and dependencies were successfully resolved.

When I deploy the .war-file now, I get an exception in Hibernate classes:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [rest] in context with path [/User] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0] with root cause
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.resultClassChecking(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:344)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:334)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at de.user.dao.UserDao.findAll(UserDao.java:19)
    at de.user.dao.UserDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$94619575.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at de.user.dao.UserDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b18c3ff9.findAll(<generated>)
    at de.user.service.UserService.findAll(UserService.java:16)
    at de.user.controller.MyController.findAll(MyController.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

For completion's sake, here's my UserDao.java (line 19 is the return statement):

```
package de.user.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import de.user.entity.User;

@Repository
public class UserDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return this.em.createQuery("from " + User.class.getName(), User.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

As you might imagine this is not the actual project I'm working on, I drafted this simple scenario to reproduce the problem (which it does).
I'm looking forward to any constructive advice and thank you in advance for any effort you put into helping me with this annoying issue!

edit: as requested, here is the User.java entity class:

```
package de.user.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the User database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6986289036842149115L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

}
```

Comment: I hope you're referring to the Hibernate version, that would be:  <hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>

Comment: The dao class is already included in the post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix this "no persistent classes found for query class" message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844521/how-do-i-fix-this-no-persistent-classes-found-for-query-class-message)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. In my case, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException was thrown by org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl#resultClassChecking because I forgot to add entity to persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public List<User> findAll() {
        return  em.createQuery("select u from User u ").getResultList();
    }
```

Provide mapping to your User entity

```
 @Id
 @column(name="your table id column name")
 @generatedValue
private int id;

@column(name="your table Firstname column name")
private String firstname;

@column(name="your table lastname column name")
private String lastname;
```

This Should work!

Comment: `public List<User> findAll() { return this.em.createQuery("select u from User u").getResultList(); }`

leads to

--- org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
--- org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [select u from User u]; nested exception is 
--- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
--- org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [select u from User u]] with root cause
--- org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped

Comment: can you share your user entity ?

Comment: I edited the initial question and added the entity to the bottom of the post. The class was created by Eclipse's JPA entity from tables wizard.

Comment: Hey, I added the annotations, the column names are the same as the field names `@Column(name="firstname") private String firstname;` 

Unfortunately the error remains...

Comment: can you update the latest entity ? I guess ter should be a problem with mapping only

Comment: Hey, I updated the entity to the youngest version (with your changes implemented). Just FYI my weekend begins soon. As much as I appreciate your help, I'd get back to you on Monday. x)